# layout_weight with fragment and linear layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-layout-weight

I am trying to make a two pane layout for my app, and i'm trying to use `layout_weight` but its not working correctly. It looks like it's reversed so that the view with more weight is smaller but when I checked it didn't even do that. Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bookList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fmtEditBook"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:name="com.perlib.wmbg.fragments.EditBookFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_book" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `LinearLayout` has width `wrap_content`, change it to `match_parent`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason why this happens, but if you change the `layout_width` of the root element to `match_parent` it will work correctly.